# Prove That PDF is ≥ 0 for all real numbers

Tags: random-variables

I am taking my first stats course and struggling quite a bit as my professor does not explain things well. I wanted to double check that I am on the right track.
My question is: Show that  $f(x)≥0$ for all $x ∈ R$ , where $x$ is the exponential density function:$$f(x) = \begin{cases}λ\operatorname e^{−λx} & \text{if }x ≥ 0,\\ 0   & \text{if }x<0\end{cases}$$

Could I prove this by taking the limit of the exponential density function both as x approaches negative and positive infinity?

Comment: The exponential function is always positive.

Comment: Your problem comes down to showing $e^t>0$ where $x\in \mathbb{R}$. You can definitely show this using the method you described (with a couple of caveats). You could show that for an arbitrarily large negative $t$ the function is positive, and that it is increasing.

Comment: Or.... assume the opposite... that there is at least one $x$ for which $e^{- \lambda x}$ is negative.  By continuity, there must then be another (smaller) $x^*$ for which $e^{- \lambda x^*} = 0$.  Take the logarithm of both sides...

Comment: @Numeral I see what you are saying. For an arbitrarily large t, the function is obviously positive and increasing. Then I am thinking of showing as x approaches positive infinity to prove that it approaches zero from that direction as well.

Comment: By definition, the density is always non-negative.